# What is the use of Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

As a technology, we understand the docker creates virtualization and there is a docker hub, where Docker images are stored.
To explain in simple words, what purpose does docker desktop serve?
Or why do I need to install Docker Desktop App to use Docker
If we need to use docker on linux server, do we need to install Docker Desktop there as well or there is some other way?

Comment: I cannot find the answer to this either.  Is it for running vm’s with desktops, or maybe it only works on systems with a desktop? This implies there a “docker server” product also. Or did they rebrand docker to docker desktop? Should I take the regular docker, or desktop docker?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docker as technology can only be run on Linux OS.

Docker Desktop does 2 things.

1. creates Linux VM on your host OS (Windows / Mac)
2. forwards docker-cli commands from the host OS to created Linux VM --> due to this the containers are created on Linux VM, and on the surface it appears to be working on Windows/Mac

Thus we are able to run and use docker-cli on Windows/Mac even though these OS's do not support docker images/containers.

Answer (score 7):

Docker Deskop packages a managed VM for running containers with various developer focused features. Some of the highlights include:

- A managed immutable VM for running containers that makes recovering from issues typically as easy as a restart.
- Automatic upgrades to apply security fixes.
- Mapping of networking connections from the VM back to the desktop, allowing developers to point to `localhost` instead of tracking down the current IP of their VM.
- Syncing filesystems between the host and containers so developers can write their code on their desktop and do their testing in a container as if it was on the same host.
- GUI for managing containers and debugging issues. There's still the CLI if you prefer.
- Kubernetes deployed with a toggle switch. Alternatives to this include KinD , k3s, and MiniKube.
- Windows containers are available on Docker for Windows.
- Bundled and preconfigured tooling with the newest features. For example, scanning, `docker compose` (v2), Dev environments, multi-platform support, were all released early on Docker Desktop.

For me, if you're a Windows or Mac user that doesn't want to be a Linux administrator, and wants your development experience to appear as if it's all running on your laptop instead of ssh'ing files to the server, Docker Desktop fills a nice role.

Further reading:

- https://docs.docker.com/desktop/
- https://www.docker.com/blog/the-magic-behind-the-scenes-of-docker-desktop/

Answer (score 3):

The goal of **Docker desktop** is to deliver an easy-to-use development environment for building, shipping, and running dockerized apps. This is a way to allow [Environment Parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) from the [Twelve Factor App](https://12factor.net/) guideline and decrease the resource gap between the development and production environment. So you can run a containerized application in your environment the same way it runs on production.

In addition, Docker can be referenced as **[Docker Platform](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/)**, an open platform for developing, shipping, and running applications where it had all these things:

- A container image format
- A method for building container images (Dockerfile/docker build)
- A way to manage container images (docker images, docker rm , etc.)
- A way to manage instances of containers (docker ps, docker rm , etc.)
- A way to share container images (docker push/pull)
- A way to run containers (docker run)

All these things are ways of work with [Containers](https://www.opencontainers.org/) where [container runtime](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/container-runtimes-part-1-introduction-container-r) plays an important role in this field. Docker uses [Containerd](https://www.docker.com/blog/what-is-containerd-runtime/) as runtime but you have many [other](https://landscape.cncf.io/category=container-runtime&format=card-mode&grouping=category) choices available.

Comment: What is docker then without docker desktop? means we are discussing that further anyone who reads should remember for always?

Comment: Good question @AkshayVijayJain. I edited my answer and added my information. Tks

Comment: These answers are about docker, not docker desktop.